# Virtual box on windows

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox

I installed Sun virtualbox in windows 7 as admin user.  When I logged in as user i can run the virtual box but the installed vms are not visible.  How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

When you installed and ran virtual box as admin, your default vm directory was under admin's home directory. So the vms you crated then belonged to admin account.

When you switched to your own user, those vms that you created can't be acces because they belong to admin.

On a single user station (only you on the computer) you can create a global VM directory (example \vm).